# Cakephp set function not passing variables from controller to the view

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to pass variable to the view and this one is very weird as the naming and directory structure is correct. Below is the function in my controller:

```
public function validate_apply_link(){
        App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

        $this->layout = 'blank';

        $listings = $this->CareersAndJob->query("
            SELECT l.sid, l.title, lp.value, u.CompanyName, u.WebSite
            FROM listings l
            LEFT JOIN listings_properties lp
            ON lp.object_sid = l.sid
            LEFT JOIN users u
            ON u.sid = l.user_sid
            WHERE l.active = 1
            AND lp.add_parameter = 2
            AND l.JobGateSenderReference IS NULL
            AND u.CompanyName != 'AECOM'
            ORDER BY u.CompanyName ASC
            LIMIT 5
            ");

        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        ob_start();
        $listing_count = count($listings);
        echo nl2br("Checking $listing_count active jobs...\n\n");
        $i=0;
        foreach($listings as $listing){

            $sid = $listing['l']['sid'];
            $url = $listing['lp']['value'];
            $company_name = $listing['u']['CompanyName'];
            $title = htmlspecialchars($listing['l']['title']);

            $length = strpos($title, "-");
            if($length != 0){
                $title = substr($title, 0, $length-1);
            }
            $title = substr($title, 0, $length-1);
            $title = substr($title, 0, 10);
            $data = $this->curl($url);

            $check_pdf = strpos($data['info']['content_type'], "pdf");
            if($check_pdf != false){
                $outputs['data'][$i]['url'] = $url;
                $outputs['data'][$i]['sid'] = $sid;
                $outputs['data'][$i]['title'] = $title;
                $outputs['data'][$i]['company_name'] = $company_name;
                $outputs['data'][$i]['our_link'] = "http://careersandjobs.com.au/display-job/{$sid}";
                $outputs['data'][$i]['content_type'] = $data['info']['content_type'];

                $outputs['data'][$i]['data_type'] = 'pdf';

                $i++;
                continue;
            }

            @$doc->loadHTML($data['results']);
            $html = $doc->saveHTML();
            $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

            $body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);

            $parsed_url = parse_url($url);

            switch($parsed_url['host']){
                case "www.michaelpage.com.au":
                    parse_str($url);
                    $exist = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@value,'{$ref}')]");

                break;
                case "https://vacancies.mackay.qld.gov.au":
                    parse_str($url);
                    $exist = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@value,'{$title}')]");
                break;
                default:
                    $exist = $xpath->query("//*[contains(text(),'{$title}')]");
                break;
            }

            if($exist->length == 0){

                if(strpos($url, '#') == false){

                $outputs['data'][$i]['url'] = $url;
                $outputs['data'][$i]['sid'] = $sid;
                $outputs['data'][$i]['title'] = $title;
                $outputs['data'][$i]['company_name'] = $company_name;
                $outputs['data'][$i]['our_link'] = "http://careersandjobs.com.au/display-job/{$sid}";
                $outputs['data'][$i]['content_type'] = $data['info']['content_type'];

                $response_code = $this->http_response_codes($data['info']['http_code']);
                $outputs['data'][$i]['response_code'] = $response_code;

                $outputs['data'][$i]['data_type'] = 'title_not_found';


                }else{

                    $outputs['data'][$i]['data_type'] = 'no_iframe';
                }

                $i++;
            }

            flush();
            ob_flush();

        }

        $this->set(compact('outputs'));

    }
```

I can do `pr` on the `outputs` variable in the view but this outputs to `NULL` but when I delete the entire bunch of code inside the controller function and just pass a test variable through it works.

Is there something wrong with the function that I am not aware of?

No errors were found in the above function by the way

```
app/Controller/CareersAndJobsController.php (line 1048)
array(
    'data' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'url' => 'http://bawbawshire.currentjobs.com.au/cvbuilder/apply+for+this+job/no/1225055',
            'sid' => '3649',
            'title' => 'Graduate P',
            'company_name' => 'Baw Baw Shire Council',
            'our_link' => 'http://careersandjobs.com.au/display-job/3649',
            'content_type' => 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
            'response_code' => 'OK',
            'data_type' => 'title_not_found'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'url' => 'http://bawbawshire.currentjobs.com.au/cvbuilder/apply+for+this+job/no/1225724',
            'sid' => '3726',
            'title' => 'Program &a',
            'company_name' => 'Baw Baw Shire Council',
            'our_link' => 'http://careersandjobs.com.au/display-job/3726',
            'content_type' => 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
            'response_code' => 'OK',
            'data_type' => 'title_not_found'
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'url' => 'http://bawbawshire.currentjobs.com.au/cvbuilder/apply+for+this+job/no/1225826',
            'sid' => '3727',
            'title' => 'Road Netwo',
            'company_name' => 'Baw Baw Shire Council',
            'our_link' => 'http://careersandjobs.com.au/display-job/3727',
            'content_type' => 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
            'response_code' => 'OK',
            'data_type' => 'title_not_found'
        )
    )
)
```

This is what I am getting from `outputs` variable just before it gets set by the set function in controller

Answer (score -1):

Any reason you chose to use CakePHP? Because you seem to *not* make use of its functionality!

You're using literal SQL queries, therefore basically skipping the Models [functionality](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html).

You're outputting your content from your [*Controller*](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/cakephp-overview/understanding-model-view-controller.html)? Be careful when using output buffering, this may conflict with CakePHP's inner workings, which also relies on output buffering in many cases. Because you're already outputting the content here (ob_flush()), you'll be outputting your content before  your View is reached..

Normally I would point to specific [points](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) in the manual, however, because there's so much wrong here, I would suggest to start reading at the [beginning](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html)

Comment: you're not answering my question I know how MVC works and SQL queries or any Model functions should be used inside the model but what I'm asking is why is the variable not passing across to the view. Your answer is very generic and anyone could answer it this way. I think we need to be more specific for people who might be looking for answers to similar problem. (After all this is what stackoverflow is about. Sharing knowledge) I've also tried taking out ob_flush but it still does not work...

Comment: What is the content of `$outputs` if you try to debug it? E.g. Put `debug($outputs);` Just before you call `$this->set(compact('outputs'));`. The `$outputs` variable does not seem to be declared/initialised implicitly and may not exist if certain conditions are not met in your code

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question. Please refer to the output I am getting just before the set function. I'm presuming if I declare DomDocument and DomXPath, that's where I'm getting errors. If so, I might have to report to Cake team themselves to see it as a bug

Comment: Those classes are part of PHP itself, not CakePHP; http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php. What happens if you disable all output buffering? You may be having errors, but suppressing them because the output buffer catches them?

Comment: As mentioned at my initial comment at the top, I have tried taking out all of the flushes and also I have no errors. I am also aware that those are core classes of PHP itself